# list.indexOf(numerical value) return -1

Tags: java

I have one list that contains numerical value like this:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
```

I want to have index of first 2,i use List.indexOf("2") but it return -1
what is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

If your list is storing numbers, you receive -1 because your passing a String into the indexOf method.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);

list.indexOf("1");//returns -1
list.indexOf(1);//returns 0
```

When doing the comparison internally within `indexOf` it checks for equality which takes type into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

"2" is a String, while your List contains Integers. Try `List.indexOf(new Integer(2));`

Answer (score 1):

-1 means, that the searched value is not contained in your list.

are the contents of the list really strings?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `List.indexOf(2);` instead of `List.indexOf("2");`

Since, your question says that you have numerical data in your `List` object, you will have to pass an argument as a number instead of a `String`. Unless you are storing your data in the form of `String`, you will receive `-1` as the result.

Answer (score 0):

you are searching 2 as a string. Try `List.indexOf(2)`

Answer (score 0):

As you pass 2 as "2". it consider as a String. 
If you want to fetch data from list you have pass like List.indexOf(new Integer(2));
or List.indexOf(new Integer(Any number));

Answer (score 0):

As Katja says, you are probably looking for the wrong type (String) in your List (I assume it's a List of **Integer**).

See example below:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

list.add(1);
list.add(2);

System.out.println(list.indexOf("1"));
System.out.println(list.indexOf(1));
```

Output:

```
-1
0
```